# Правильная структура БД

Tags: mysql, база-данных, структуры

Прочитал [статью на хабре](https://habrahabr.ru/company/mailru/blog/282375/) о том, как создавался антиспам для почты.
Мне стало очень интересно, как при подобном логировании действий правильно хранить этот самый лог в базе данных. Какая примерно **структура** у базы данных при таком подходе. 
Как хранится в базе данных информация по **"Возможным паттернам(скриншот)"**. Явно не строкой.
Этот вопрос, который затрагивает правильное построение баз данных не дает мне покоя.

[image: Возможные паттерны[3]]

Comment: А почему бы строкой не хранить? Если у вас массив возможных паттернов, то сериализуйте его и храните строкой. (Это при условии что не понадобится фильтровать данные при выборке из этой таблицы).

Comment: Как не понадобится? Безусловно, понадобится)

Answer (score 2):

```
CREATE TABLE actions (
    action varchar PRIMARY KEY;
    ...
);

CREATE TABLE possible_patterns (
    id int PRIMARY KEY;
    ...
);

CREATE TABLE possible_patterns_actions (
    pattern_id int; -- шаблон
    action varchar; -- действие
    index int;      -- порядковый номер действия в шаблоне
    FOREIGN KEY (pattern_id) REFERENCES possible_patterns(id);
    FOREIGN KEY (action) REFERENCES actions(action);
);

-- получить действия из паттерна 123 по порядку
SELECT a.* 
  FROM possible_patterns_actions pa 
  JOIN actions a ON a.action = pa.action
 WHERE pa.pattern_id = 123
 ORDER BY pa.index
```